# basis and dimension of the splitting field of $x^4+5x^2+6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Please help me finding the basis and dimension of the splitting field of the polynomial $x^4+5x^2+6$ in the rational field.

Thanks

Comment: Step one: factor that polynomial. I'm sure you can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can factor this as $(x^2+3)(x^2+2)$ so the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3})$. You should then apply the tower rule to get that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3}][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2}):\mathbb{Q}]$. To find each of the degrees in the product try and find the degree of the minimal polynomial. The hint for this is that a quadratic annihilates things and so you'r each degree 1 or 2 at each step--then recall that you're degree one only if you were in the field all along!

Comment: Now we'll never know whether OP can factor polynomials.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I couldn't either--I used wolfram :)

Comment: Wolfram? to factor a quadratic??

Comment: @GerryMyerson You can restore your faith in mathematical humanity--it was a joke :)

Comment: You don't know how much better I feel now.

Comment: Ok, then am I wrong if the basis is {1, √2 i,√3 i,-√6} and the dimension is 4 ?

Comment: No, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here, x=±√2 i,±√3 i. So splitting field is Q(√2 i,√3 i) whose elements are of the form Q((√2 i) )(√3 i)=Q_1 (√3 i), in particular, {q_0+q_1 (√2 i);q_i ϵQ_1} that is {(a_0+a_1 √2 i)+(a_2+a_3 √2 i)√3 i;a_i ϵQ}. Therefore, basis is {1,√2 i,√3 i,-√6} and dimension is 4